# Struct value changes after accessing it twice

Tags: function, pointers, struct

When I try to access the age element from my struct (using a function that accepts a double pointer), I only get the correct value on the first try. Why is it changing? Is the pointer moving?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    int age; 
    char name[200];
} student;


int getAge(student **s){
    int a = (*s)->age;
    return a;
}

student *create(){
    student st;
    student *mp = &st;
    st.age = 25;
    
    return mp;
}

int main()
{
    student *sp = create();
    int myAge = getAge(&sp);    
    printf("I am %d\n", myAge);
    int Age = getAge(&sp);
    printf("Again, I am %d\n", Age);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is. Your `create()` function creates a student on the stack and sets `mp` to point to it. When the `create()` function returns, (or maybe some time after) `mp` points to nowhere in particular since the stack frame it was pointing into was destroyed.

Please try using `malloc` to create a student in your `create` function:

```
student *mp = malloc(sizeof student);
```

Or if this is C++ code:

```
student *mp = new student;
```

Remember to `free` (if C) or `delete` (C++) `sp` in your `main` function when you are done with it to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nathan. Unfortunately, it's still returning a 10-digit number the second time. I changed the create() function to the following:

Comment: ```student *create(){
    student st;
    st.age = 25;
    student *mp = malloc(sizeof(student));
    mp = &st;
    //student *mp = &st;
    
    return mp;
}```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `mp = &st;` line? Also use `mp->age` instead of `st.age` otherwise age will be 0.

Comment: Removing ```mp = &st``` results in age = 0 for both queries. It does fix the invalid pointer error I received when using free(sp).

Comment: Make sure to set `mp->age = 25` after calling `malloc` so that the returned student struct has a valid age.